# Unique link to an artifact deployed to JFrog Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I'm a new Artifactory user. My company just setup Artifactory v6.5.2 and I'm looking to use is for managing software deployed for our production team. What I need is a download link that will get documented in our product management system that directly points to the exact file that Software deployed for Production to use. I was anticipating this would look like this:

https://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/mymodule/mypkgfile_v1_b30b890becfb4a02510ed12a7283c676.tgz

I'm not seeing that Artifactory can do this for me.  What I see is I can do this:

http://artifactory.mycompany.com/artifactory/myrepo/mymodule/mypkgfile_v1.tgz

However if another artifact is deployed with the same name, it's not reflected in the download link. This means that the link could return different results.

Am I missing something or am I asking Artifactory do something it's not intended to do?

Comment: If another artifact is deployed with the same name (at the same path), it will overwrite the old artifact which will no longer be available (except from the trash, I think). If you want to deploy a different artifact, why not use a different name?

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory returns the URL based on on the filename and the path (as any web server would do). Here are two options to achieve what you need:

1. Name the artifacts uniquely (timestamps are the simplest). Instead of naming the artifact `mypkgfile_v1.tgz`, name it `mypkgfile_v1-1553038888.tgz` (I used the Unix Epoch time, but everything unique enough will do).
2. This one is more evolved but doesn't require you to change the naming scheme.

   1. First, configure [a custom repository layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) to match your versioning.
   2. Once you've done that, every time you deploy an artifact, attach a unique identifier to the artifact as property during deployment (using [matrix params](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution), for example), deploying your artifact as `mypkgfile_v1;timestamp=1553038888`.
   3. On the revrieval, [use the token for the latest release](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact) together with the timestamp you need as [a matrix param](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+Properties+in+Deployment+and+Resolution):`mypkgfile_v[RELEASE];timestamp=1553038888`